# bootstrap input file (change) event not getting triggered

Tags: html, angular, twitter-bootstrap

Angular4 app using the bootstrap input file to allow the user to select files from disk.

in my HTML, i have the following

```
<label class="btn btn-primary">
    Import
    <input type="file" (change)="import($event)" hidden>
</label>
```

it turns out if I select file1 from the file picker and click OK, the import function gets called. If I do some other things and I click on the file picker to show the file selection dialog and I still click on file1, I don't get the import function since I think there was no change as far as the file picker is concerned.

Are there other events that I can use so whenever the user selects a file and press ok, I get called?

Or any other thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use JQuery, you could run the file with

```
<input id="file" onchange="file_changed(this)" onclick="this.value=null;" type="file" accept="*/*" />
```

```html
<form enctype='multipart/form-data'>
  <input onchange="alert(this.value); return false;" type='file'>
  <br>
  <input type='submit' value='Upload'>
</form>
```

With JQuery

```js
let $c  = $("#container");
let $f1 = $("#container .f1");

function FChange() {
    alert("f1 changed");
    
    $(this).remove();
    $("<input type='file' class='f1' />").change(FChange).appendTo($c);
}

$f1.change(FChange);
```

```css
.f1 { z-index: 2 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
    <input type="file" class="f1">
</div>
```

Remove the file element and add it in the same place on change event. It will erase the file path making it changeable every time.